# How to improve testing coverage in Go?

Tags: testing, go

I am doing some testing. I have a file dao.go:

```
package model_dao
import "io/ioutil"
const fileExtension = ".txt"
type Page struct {
    Title string
    Body  []byte
}
func (p Page) SaveAsFile() (e error) {
    p.Title = p.Title + fileExtension
    return ioutil.WriteFile(p.Title, p.Body, 0600)
}
func LoadFromFile(title string) (*Page, error) {
    fileName := title + fileExtension
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Page{title, body}, nil
}
```

And a test file dao_test.go:

```
package model_dao_test
import (
    "shopserver/model/dao"
    "testing"
)
func TestDAOFileWorks(t *testing.T) {
    TITLE := "test"
    BODY := []byte("Hello, World!!")
    p := &model_dao.Page{TITLE, BODY}
    p.SaveAsFile()
    p, _ = model_dao.LoadFromFile(TITLE)
    result := p.Body
    if string(BODY) != string(result) {
        t.Error("Body", BODY, "saved.\n", "Load:", result)
    }
}
```

Here I test all 2 methods from *Page*, but after testing I see a message:

[image]

Why do I only get 85.7%? Where he get this numbers and how to get 100%?

Comment: Probably because you're never testing the error path. You may want to [read up on how cover works](https://blog.golang.org/cover).

Comment: "how to get 100%?" Don't. And if you must: Lie. :-)

Comment: Note that "plz", "dunno", "bout" (etc) here is usually a lightning conductor for downvotes. It is a fairly reliable indicator of the (lack of) effort that went into a post. Use real words instead, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "[The Go Blog - The cover story](https://blog.golang.org/cover)"

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out 
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

That would display an HTML representation of your source file, where you will clearly see which lines are or are not covered by your test.

[image: https://blog.golang.org/cover/set.png]

Other Go testing framework would show you the same visualization as well.
Seee for instance **[GoConvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey)**.

Comment: thanks a lot man - dunno 'bout go tool cover with "html" flag